ZMQ Pub/Sub no support reset of publisher service node
Hi i are using ZMQ with pub/sub pattern.
I have a one node publisher and other nother subcriber, i tried with python (pyzmq) and with c++ (cppzmq)
If i start publishear service and subscriber servicio this's ok, but if i restart publishear node and start publisher service, without restart the subscriber service, the subscriber never reconected and don't see messages.
If i restart the subscription service that's ok, it's see the zmq message.
We sniffer the trafic in port and we see that subscriber never try reconecting and the publishear i think that wait for a new subcription.
¿ZMQ dont support restart in the publishear o maiby i have a bad settings?

Code for reproduce problem:
subscriber.py
import zmq
import sys

def subscriber():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.connect(sys.argv[1])

    # Suscribirse a todos los mensajes
    socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')

    while True:
        message = socket.recv_string()
        print(f"Received: {message}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    subscriber()

Run with python subscriber.py tcp://localhost:5555
publisher.py
import zmq
import time

def publisher():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

    while True:
        message = "Hello, World!"
        socket.send_string(message)
        print(f"Sent: {message}")
        time.sleep(0.5) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    publisher()

Run with python publisher.py
Note: for reproduce de error need isolate the publisher node, i used a virtual machine but maybe can use docker.
Steps:

Start subscriber
Start publisher
Reboot publisher VM
Start publisher
I don't see the new messages in the subscriber


Can you post a [mre] that we could test with? I imagine a python version would be shorter.

Hi pmacfarlane, i add code and steeps for reproduce error.

Running your code on the same machine. I can restart both the publisher and subscriber at will and it all works as expected. I don't have the energy to test the new part of your problem, that it needs to be run in a VM that you reboot.

What you get is expected since PUB/SUB is not a reliable protocol. To debug your issue, follow a flow diagram from here.
If it doesn't help, I recommend you properly terminate zmq's Context by invoking context.destroy() before restarting the VM.
Switching to XPUB/XSUB protocol may also help in your case.
